# Layer positioning is working only for 4.3 target

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, cocos2d-iphone

I made `UIScrollView` based Cocos layer scrolling mechanism and here is part of the code from `UIScrollView` derived class:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)scrollFrame contentFrame:(CGRect)contentFrame layer:(CCNode*)layer anchor:(int)anchor_
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:scrollFrame];
    if (self) {
        self.contentSize = contentFrame.size;
        self.delegate = self;
        self.bounces = YES;
        self.delaysContentTouches = NO;
        self.pagingEnabled = YES;
        self.scrollsToTop = NO;
        self.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
        self.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;

        self.alwaysBounceHorizontal = YES;
        self.alwaysBounceVertical = YES;
        self.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateNormal;

        [self setUserInteractionEnabled:TRUE];
        [self setScrollEnabled:TRUE];
        self.targetLayer = layer;
        anchor = anchor_;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGPoint dragPt = [scrollView contentOffset];
    dragPt = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:dragPt];
    dragPt.y = targetLayer.position.y;
    dragPt.x = dragPt.x * -1 + anchor;
    CGPoint newLayerPosition = CGPointMake(dragPt.x, dragPt.y);
    [targetLayer setPosition:newLayerPosition];
}
```

It takes new offset and moves target layer. Very strange that I started this project using 4.3 as target iOS version and layers was scrolling just fine. Today I tried on 5.0/above and... I see in debugger the new offset but layer simply doesn't change it's position on screen during the scroll. Only when the page changes I can instantly see new portion of layer. I suspect something has to do with Cocos 2.0.

Update: 
this is what I had working on 4.3

http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=xp6bPyAVShk

Again, this doesn't work on iOS 5 or above. I don't have a clue where to look for problem, what to search... little help please.

Comment: I've solved the issue by changing run loop to `NSRunLoopCommonModes`. Not sure what's the difference between `NSRunLoopCommonModes` and `NSDefaultRunLoopMode`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a **CCScrollView** from CCBReader libs

here i add the github repository 
https://github.com/cocos2d/CCBReader

this libs is about reader of Cocos Builder, a graphical interface builder for Cocos2D, its free

Cocos2D not recommends the use of uikit over cocos layer, the CCScrollView is easy to implement and works with the last version of cocos2D and target 4.3 and above.

**EDIT:** 
the **CCScrollLayer** suport paging
here the GitHub repository

https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone-extensions/tree/master/Extensions/CCScrollLayer

maybe you need modify a little bit this classes for the touch delegate in the new version of cocos2D

Comment: The reason I am usin UIScrollView is to get bouncing effect and paging. From sources it seems CCScrollView support decelerating. But how about paging support?

Comment: ok, in my case i use CCScrollLayer is a cocos2d extension, edit the post with information

Comment: CCScrollLayer does support paging, but does NOT support bouncing/deceleration.